# Liminf, Limsup inequalities in Cesàro's Lemma proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, inequality, limsup-and-liminf

Probability with Martingales:

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

I tried writing out the details of the proof avoiding $\ge$ if I felt it was unnecessary. Please tell me if I got any steps wrong.

$$\liminf \frac{1}{b_n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} (b_k - b_{k-1})v_k$$

$$\color{red}{=} \liminf \frac{1}{b_n} \left[\sum_{k=1}^{N} (b_k - b_{k-1})v_k + \sum_{k=N+1}^{n} (b_k - b_{k-1})v_k \right] \tag{1}$$

$$\color{red}{>} \liminf \frac{1}{b_n} \left[\sum_{k=1}^{N} (b_k - b_{k-1})v_k + \sum_{k=N+1}^{n} (b_k - b_{k-1})(v_{\infty} - \epsilon) \right] \tag{2}$$

$$\color{red}{=} \liminf \frac{1}{b_n} \left[\sum_{k=1}^{N} (b_k - b_{k-1})v_k + (v_{\infty} - \epsilon)\sum_{k=N+1}^{n} (b_k - b_{k-1}) \right] \tag{3}$$

$$\color{red}{=} \liminf \frac{1}{b_n} \left[\sum_{k=1}^{N} (b_k - b_{k-1})v_k + (v_{\infty} - \epsilon)(b_n - b_{N+1}) \right] \tag{4}$$

$$\color{red}{\ge} \liminf \frac{1}{b_n} \left[\sum_{k=1}^{N} (b_k - b_{k-1})v_k\right] +  \liminf \frac{1}{b_n} \left[(v_{\infty} - \epsilon)(b_n - b_{N+1}) \right] \tag{5}$$

$$\color{red}{=} 0 +  \liminf \frac{1}{b_n} \left[(v_{\infty} - \epsilon)(b_n - b_{N+1}) \right] \tag{6}$$

$$\color{red}{=} 0 +  (v_{\infty} - \epsilon) \tag{7}$$

---

On $(6)$:

$$\liminf \frac{1}{b_n} \left[\sum_{k=1}^{N} (b_k - b_{k-1})v_k\right] \stackrel{?}{=} \frac{1}{\liminf b_n} \left[\sum_{k=1}^{N} (b_k - b_{k-1})v_k\right]$$

---

On $(7)$:

$$\liminf \frac{1}{b_n} \left[(v_{\infty} - \epsilon)(b_n - b_{N+1}) \right]$$

$$ \color{red}{=} (v_{\infty} - \epsilon) \liminf \frac{1}{b_n} \left[b_n - b_{N+1} \right] \tag{7.1}$$

$$ \color{red}{=} (v_{\infty} - \epsilon) \liminf \left[1 - \frac{b_{N+1}}{b_n} \right] \tag{7.2}$$

$$ \color{red}{=} (v_{\infty} - \epsilon) \left[1 - \liminf \frac{b_{N+1}}{b_n} \right] \tag{7.3}$$

$$ \color{red}{=} (v_{\infty} - \epsilon) \left[1 - \frac{b_{N+1}}{\liminf b_n} \right] \tag{7.4}$$

Comment: $(2)$ should be $\ge$ (why $>$?). $(6)$ and $(7)$ are straightforward from $\lim\inf \frac{C}{b_n} = 0$ if $C$ is constant and $b_n\to \infty$.

Comment: @Khue 2 $v_k > v_{\infty} - \epsilon$ 6,7 Does that apply to limsup too?

Comment: Be careful: when taking the limit, $>$ becomes $\ge$! Yes, the property still holds for $\lim\sup$. More generally, we have $\lim u_n = L \Longleftrightarrow \lim\inf u_n = \lim\sup u_n = L$.

Comment: @Khue ah thanks, post as answer? Wait what's the relevance of the last part? You're assuming the limit exists?

Comment: Apply the last property for $u_n = \frac{C}{b_n}$, what do you get? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $(2)$, the sign $>$ should be replaced by $\ge$ (note that when taking the limit, $>$ will become $\ge$).

Notice that $\lim\inf\frac{C}{b_n} = 0$ as $b_n\to \infty$ for any constant $C$, it is straightforward to obtain $(6)$ and $(7)$ from $(5)$:
\begin{align}
&\liminf \frac{1}{b_n} \left[\sum_{k=1}^{N} (b_k - b_{k-1})v_k\right] +  \liminf \frac{1}{b_n} \left[(v_{\infty} - \epsilon)(b_n - b_{N+1}) \right] \tag{5} \\
= &\liminf \frac{C_1}{b_n} +  \liminf  \left(v_{\infty} - \epsilon + \frac{- b_{N+1}(v_{\infty} - \epsilon)}{b_n} \right) \\
=& \liminf \frac{C_1}{b_n} +  \liminf  \left(\frac{C_2}{b_n} \right) + v_{\infty} - \epsilon \\
= & 0 + 0 + v_{\infty} - \epsilon
\end{align}
where $C_1 = \left[\sum_{k=1}^{N} (b_k - b_{k-1})v_k\right]$ and $C_2 = - b_{N+1}(v_{\infty} - \epsilon)$.

Comment: You are welcome, @BCLC ;)